# Colorpass and RIP for digital printing

Tags: digital-printing

Could someone explain me what a colorpass and rip are, why some printers have external colorpass units and others don't? Usually the printing software asks me whether I want to do the color management locally or on the colorpass, so I guess everything the colorpass does, can be done on my PC as well. Colorpass is just a PC as well...

Sorry for the noob question, but I really don't get it...

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question is probably off-topic here on GDSE. You are asking about Canon hardware, which really has nothing much to do with graphic design.  Perhaps you would be better asking about these products on a Canon forum.

Comment: I am not asking about Canon hardware, but about the color pass in general. Don't other brand offer their own color management stuff?

Comment: I think it's a valid question, from the angle of 'why do I need a dedicated RIP/color manager if I can do it with my computer?'

Comment: Exactly! What is it, what does it do and why do I need a dedicated unit for it?